# s3 upload issue with cloudberry explorer

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudberry

I created a new bucket test1 and it has two folders upload and download.Below is my policy attached to a user. i connected using aws cli with access and secret access keys and was successfully able to upload a document to s3://test1/upload/. Using cloudberry explorer when i try to upload to s3://test1/upload/ folder it fails with 403 forbidden error. I am using the same keys to connect to aws cli and cloudberry but not sure what is causing the issue.Can any one please help with this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
          "Effect": "Allow"
      },
      {
          "Action": [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetBucketLocation"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test1",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                     "s3:prefix": [
                          "",
                          "/",
                          "download/",
                          "download/*",
                          "upload/",
                          "upload/*"
                        ]
                      }
               }
     },
     {
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test1/download/*",
         "Effect": "Allow"
     },
     {
         "Action": [
         "s3:GetObject",
         "s3:PutObject",
         "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test1/upload/*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Indentation helps read code and policies too.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are trying to upload to: "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test1/upload/*" and not to "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test1" or to "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test1/download/*"

Comment: indented the code. Yes i am trying to upload to s3://test1/upload/ folder. From aws cli i am able to successfully but not from clouberry explorer

Comment: What policies do you have for the AWS access key and secret key that you used to connect cloudberry to your AWS account? If this is a different access key from the one you use with the CLI that might be the issue.

Comment: there is only one inline policy for this user and that policy is posted above. i am using exactly the same access and secret keys when trying to connect to from cli and cloudberry

Comment: anyone has anything to say on this issue?

Comment: Are you able to download?

Comment: yes i am able to download. only uploading to s3://test1/upload/ fails in cloudberry explorer

Answer (score 0):

Could you try Fiddler for traffic checking? For better understanding where your request faced with 403 error.

Let me know.